# How to create a list of items in an Excel cell, and be able to data filter this column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

**Can we have a *list* of items in an Excel cell, such that the rows can be filtered with Data Filter?**

Exemple: how to filter by column `B` and keep only the rows that contain `[item4]`:

[image]

?

Notes:

- we *could* filter column B by "contains text [item4]" but then we have to enter this text *manually* or copy/paste it - I'm looking for an easier solution with fewer actions/clicks.
- I have watched [this video](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-create-and-manage-drop-down-lists-28db87b6-725f-49d7-9b29-ab4bc56cefc2), which is nearly a solution with "Data Validation", but finally not, because it only creates a dropdown list with only 1 selected item.
- Here is a beginning of solution: [Implement tags in Excel in seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5_Byze35qo)
- if we want it to be useful, it should be possible to filter the rows by items *in the list*, and the filter should be populated *automatically* with all the existing items:

  [image]

  This part is probably not easy.

Comment: Maybe have a cell with a dropdown of possible values to filter on, then link that cell to a helper column and filter on that column

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Can you give an example? (maybe in an answer it would be easier)

Comment: If you can have your filter results on another tab (or section of the worksheet) and you are only filtering one item, then use @cybernetic.nomad suggestion combined with the `FILTER` function. From there you should be able to build multiple item filter.

Comment: @gns100 They’re not going to have access to FILTER() in the tagged Excel versions.

Comment: @Max which minimal version is needed? I might upgrade soon. I kept the good old 2007 because it's super super fast on some of my PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cell with a dropdown of possible values to filter on

[image]

Create a helper column with the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H$2,B2)),"Match","")
```

[image]

Filter on that column:

[image]

Sample result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with LibreOffice Calc, in one click on the Filter, but then we have to enter the name manually:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the cells in question

Data > Filter

Text Filters > Contains > item4

This works in Excel365